# Make for loop wait until queue is complete before going on

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, loops, wait

I am trying to make my loop wait until the timed queue is complete before looping agian. How can I do this?

```
for retries in 0...3 {
    do {
        let triggerTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(((2^(randomNumber*retries)*1000) + randomNumber))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: triggerTime, execute: {
            //Don't loop until this is executed
            self.socket.connect()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: i wouldn't even do a for loop, you should do something recursively while keeping track of the retries

Comment: You could also use a scheduled timer with repeat...keep track of the timer, and then terminate it when all is done.

Comment: I am writing an exponential retry so the repeats would be at different times. I don't understand how this could be done without a loop.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That's a ticking time bomb. The recursion limit is *really* low.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise `XOR` operator, not exponentiation. You need `pow(_ base: Double, _ exponent: Double)` instead.

Comment: @Alexander it is not "3 steps" low

Comment: @Knight0fDragon No, but in a few months there will be some feature request for indefinite retry, an innocent looking checking for 3 max attempts is removes, and it stack overflows. It's fragile.

Comment: @Alexander if it is done via tail recursion, then no stack is even needed and the optimizer should pick it up for you,  either way my point was we shouldn't need the for loop to be waiting, we should be doing something when we get the message that connection failed.  I am not sure what "socket" is in this case, but there should be some kind of way to be notified that a connection was successful or not, then continue along the path needed.  The OP should evaluate his strategy and ask himself if he really wants to lock up threads or not.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon My point is three-fold: 1) recursion would get OP no closer to a solution, given his current issues, 2) Recursion can bite you far too easily. You have be careful to ensure you have a tail call. There are subtle gotchas here, for example, return an object causes a `release` call after the `return`, which break tail recursion. 3) A recursive solution would be no more concise or "elegant".

Comment: I wouldn't use a loop. Use the callback or delegate methods that tell you the connection was unsuccessful and retry in that function. Use properties to keep track of the retry count and retry delay. Can you provide more information on what `socket` is.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your socket calls synchronous, but make the overall connection process (that's calling your loop) asynchronous.